# Permiso de ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION no funciona para Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocalización, android-permissions

Buenas tardes tengo un servicio de localización que me anda perfecto para dispositivos con Android > 7 pero en dispositivos de android 6.0 me falla con este error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission: android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
```

al hacer `boolean shouldProvideRationale_background = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)`

he probado preguntar por la versión y si es Marshmallow evitar preguntar por ese permiso pero simplemente no tira error pero tampoco me tomas las ubicaciones que necesito.
Ojala alguno me pueda ayudar llevo días intentando resolverlo, El permiso lo pide apenas inicia mi DashboardActivity.

les dejo secciones de codigo que considero que pueda ayudar a complementar la pregunta:

```
    /**
 * Returns the current state of the permissions needed.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        return  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) &&

                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
    }
    else {
        return  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    boolean shouldProvideRationale_background = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);


    // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
    // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
    if (shouldProvideRationale && shouldProvideRationale_background) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
        Snackbar.make(
                findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout),
                R.string.permission_rationale,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Request permission
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DashboardActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .show();
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
        // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
        // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DashboardActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
            // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
            // receive empty arrays.
            Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission was granted.
            mService.requestLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            // Permission denied.
            setButtonsState(false);
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout),
                    R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(
                                    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Receiver for broadcasts sent by {@link LocationUpdatesService}.
 */
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationUpdatesService.EXTRA_LOCATION);
        long defaultValue = 0;

        if (location != null) {
            long lastTime = PreferenceHelper.getPreference(DashboardActivity.this, "localization_update_last_time", defaultValue);
            Date timeToUpdate = new Date(lastTime);
            Date currentDate  = new Date();
            if(lastTime == 0 || currentDate.after(timeToUpdate)) {
                String update_every = PreferenceHelper.getPreference(DashboardActivity.this, "localization_update_time", "0");
                long millisToUpdate = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + Long.parseLong(update_every);

                LocationUpdater locationUpdater = new LocationUpdater(DashboardActivity.this, user.getId_personal(), location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
                locationUpdater.execute();

                PreferenceHelper.savePreference(getApplicationContext(), "localization_update_last_time", millisToUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission:
> android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Recuerda que el permiso [ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) fue agregado en la API 29, por lo tanto en tu `build.gradle`

Para usar este permiso define en tu proyecto como `targetSdkVersion` la versión `29`.

---

Si tu proyecto tiene definido como `targetSdkVersion` la versión `29`, es requisito indispensable para acceder a la geolocalización en segundo plano.

De otra forma podrías cambiar a `targetSdkVersion` con la versión `28`, pero debes tomar en cuenta que en algún momento si deseas actualizar tu aplicación te requerirá usar como mínimo el `targetSdkVersion` la versión `29`.

Recuerda lo que indica la documentación [Cumple con los requisitos de nivel de API objetivo de Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk?hl=es)

> **Las apps nuevas se deben orientar a Android 10 (nivel de API 29)*** o
> versiones posteriores y las **actualizaciones deben orientarse a Android
> 9 (nivel de API 28) o versiones posteriores**.

Comment: actualmente tengo mi targetSdkVersion en 29, el problema esta que si yo evito requerir ese permiso deja de funcionar mi servicio que obtiene las ubicaciones. y si lo requiero, me da ese error

Comment: Precisamente porque al cambiar el target ya es requisito indispensable, :-( si no lo quieres, tendrías que usar el targetSdk 28 pero en algún momento tienes que actualizar.